# What does 'this' mean in onCreate method in application subclass

Tags: java, android

In following example 'this' is used to initialize the `sinstance`.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    public static MyApplication sinstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        sinstance=this;  
    }
```

As far as I know 'this' refers to reference to the current instance of the object. Correct me if I am wrong. Now consider the following program

```
public static MyApplication sinstance;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    sinstance=new MyApplication();
}
```

`new MyApplication` is used to instantiates the `sinstance`. So why does the second program crash at runtime while the first program does not produce any errors. It gives the following error:

```
12-16 17:56:09.559 2156-2156/compdom.sad E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 10439248 byte allocation with 5527284 free bytes and 5MB until OOM"
12-16 17:56:09.559 2156-2156/compdom.sad E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 10439248 byte allocation with 5527284 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
   at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
   at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
   at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
   at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:335)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:85)
   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: You set the static  instance to the current instance on which you call the onCreate method

Comment: because you are recursivly creating new instances of `MyApplication`. Every call to `new MyApplication ()` will lead to `sinstance=new MyApplication();`, which will go on until you are out of memeory. When you call `sinstance=this` you are not explicity creating a new object and hence your code wont get stuck in an infinite task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second example is creating a never ending loop.  Each time you instantiate a new MyApplication its onCreate method is run and yet another version is created recursively.

The `this` in the first one **is** an instantiated version of your MyApplication class and you do not need to create a new one.

Answer (score 3):

As Jahnold has answered, while you try to new a instance in `onCreate()`, then the new instance will try to call its `onCreate()` too, so, the loop will never ends.

But in the first case, when you give `this` to a member variable, 'this' is just a reference, so no construction methods going to be called, nor the lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`, so it works fine.